# Is it possible (with Moq) to stub method calls with Lambda parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, mocking, moq

If I do this:

```
var repository = new Mock<IRepository<Banner>>();
repository.Setup(x => x.Where(banner => banner.Is.AvailableForFrontend())).Returns(list);
```

"Where" is a method on my repository that takes a `Func<T, ISpecification<T>`. AvailableForFrontend returns an implementation of ISpecification, and list is an IEnumberable of the generic type of the repository.

It compiles fine, but i get the following error when I run my tests.

```
---- System.NotSupportedException : Expression banner => Convert((banner.Is.AvailableForFrontend() & banner.Is.SmallMediaBanner())) is not supported.
```

If i use my other overload of Where on the repository that takes a ISpecification directly, theres no problem.

So my newbie mock / Moq question is: Can I stub a method call with a lamdba as parameter? Or should I go about this in another way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you tried the following syntax:

```
repository.Setup(x => x.Where(It.IsAny<Func<T, ISpecification<T>>()).Returns(list);
```

Comment: What about verifying that a method has been called with a specific lambda expression as a parameter? Is it possible with Moq?

repository.Verify(x => x.Where(banner => banner.Is.AvailableForFrontend()));

Comment: yes you can if you specify that it is verifiable while setting up.

repository
.Setup(x => x.Where(It.IsAny<Func<T, ISpecification<T>>())
.Returns(list)
.Verifiable();

here is the link to a setup verify example using moq:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/beginning-mocking-moq-3-part-3